# coredumps 'can only dump core to fully qualified path!'

Tags: gdb

I have a question about generating a coredumps under Debian.

First, I enable the feature trough this command :

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Next I create a Segmentation fault but I have this error :

```
[107356.139862] level0[5616]: segfault at 61616161 ip 61616161 sp bffff730 error 14
[107356.139877] Pid 5616(level0) can only dump core to fully qualified path!
[107356.139879] Skipping core dump
```

I get this message with :

```
dmesg
```

What 'can only dump core to fully qualified path!' that means ?

Thank you friends

Answer (score 0):

Core dumps are stored in the location configured by `kernel.core_pattern` sysctl. For example:

```
# sysctl kernel.core_pattern

kernel.core_pattern = /var/log/core/core.%t.%e.%p
```

In some situations, the core_pattern *must* be a full path, starting with a `/`. So if the setting just says `core` or `core.%p` (referring to the current directory), you will need to adjust it with `sysctl`.